# Build CSV from parse files python

Tags: parsing, csv, text-files

I am building a small database (for personal use), from over a 1000 files. I am looking for specific word, but the issue that I have if the word is not contained in the file how can i write a NoData line, what I would like to have is:

- Africa   Botswana    test            51.1922546  -113.9366341
- Africa   Kenya       Skydive Kenya   -13.788388  33.78498
- Africa   Malawi      Skydive Malawi  NoData          NoData
- Africa   Mauritius   SkyDive Austral     30.5000854  -8.824510574
- Africa   Morocco     Beni Mellal         NoData          NoData

> ```
> for i in os.listdir(Main_Path):
>     if "-" in i:
>         for filename in os.listdir(Main_Path+i):
>             if ".dat" in filename and os.path.isdir(Main_Path+i):
>                 f_split = filename.split("-")
>                 if len(f_split) == 4:
>                     continent.append(f_split[0])
>                     country.append(f_split[1])
>                     state.append(f_split[2].split(".")[0])
>                 else:
>                     continent.append(f_split[0])
>                     country.append("")
>                     state.append(f_split[1].split(".")[0])
>                 d = open(Main_Path+i+"/" + filename, "r")
>                 files = d.readlines()
>                 d.close()
>                 for k, line in enumerate(files):
>                     if "Dropzone.com :" in line:                        
>                         dzname.append(line.split(":")[1].strip())
>                    elif 'id="lat"' in line:
>                         lat.append(line.split("=")[3].split('"')[1].strip())
> myFile = open(Main_Path+"MYFILE.csv", "wb")
> wtr= csv.writer( myFile )
> for a,b,c,d,e in zip(continent,country,state,dzname,lat):
>     wtr.writerow([a,b,c,d,e])
> myFile.close()
> ```

I am stack "elif 'id="lat"' in line:" because it adds to the list "lat" only the files which contains id = lat. I do understand why but I would like the parser to return and add to the list an NoData

sorry i wrote the question from another comp.

Comment: Please provide some code and information about where exactly you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

That is: if no line in files contains id="lat" it will append "No Data" to lat.

```
            snip...

            d = open(Main_Path+i+"/" + filename, "r")
            files = d.readlines()
            d.close()
            found_latitude = False
            for k, line in enumerate(files):
                if "Dropzone.com :" in line:                        
                    dzname.append(line.split(":")[1].strip())
               elif 'id="lat"' in line:
                    found_latitude = True
                    lat.append(line.split("=")[3].split('"')[1].strip())
            if not found_latitude:
                lat.append("No Data")

            snip...
```

Comment: Thank you, i am such a newbee.